# How do I activate double tapping, pressing and holding keys in my iOS 8 custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, custom-keyboard

How do I activate double tapping the shift key to activate caps and pressing and holding the del key to continuously keep deleting texts in my iOS 8 custom keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

For double tap, use tap gesture recognizer and set `tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2`. Or directly override `touchesEnded` in UIView and do something when `touch.tapCount == 2`.

For press and hold, use `NSTimer` to detect this.